# numpy / pandas vectorized "threshold crossing" logic

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I would like to implement this "threshold crossing" logic (for lack of a better term):

- Start with a column `num`, and a column `switch` set to 1.
- When `num` falls to (or past) a certain `lower_bound`, turn `switch` to 0.
- Keep `switch` at 0 until `num` reaches (or exceeds) an `upper_bound`, upon which `switch` is turned back to 1.

To illustrate, here's the setup with `lower_bound` 3 and `upper_bound` 6.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([6, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 5], columns=['num'])
df['switch'] = 1
```

And here is my desired output.

```
    num switch
0   6   1
1   5   1
2   3   0
3   2   0
4   4   0
5   5   0
6   6   1
7   3   0
8   7   1
9   5   1
```

Of course one can easily iterate through, but I am looking for some ideas on a vectorized (numpy / pandas) approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do with

```
s=df.num.ge(6).astype(int)-df.num.le(3).astype(int)
s.mask(s==0).ffill().replace(-1,0).fillna(1)
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
5    0.0
6    1.0
7    0.0
8    1.0
9    1.0
Name: num, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I think another fillna call is needed to deal with the special case where the sequence starts with a number between the lower and upper bound.

Comment: @GZ0 yes you are right , we may need adding fillna(0) at the end , thanks

Comment: In the problem description, the switches are initialized with 1. So I think it should be fillna(1).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `numpy` based approach, that, while a bit verbose, should be fairly efficient.

```
a = df.num
lw, up = 3, 6

pd.Series(
    np.select([a.le(lw), a.ge(up)], [-1, 1], np.nan)
).ffill().clip(0, 1).fillna(1)
```

```
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
5    0.0
6    1.0
7    0.0
8    1.0
9    1.0
dtype: float64
```